# If somebody gets a 10 year long network-wide ban, who communicates it to them and how?

Tags: discussion, account-suspension, moderator-messages, network-wide-suspension

In the case of the bans issued by mods, the mod communicates the decision to the offender.

What happens if one gets a network-wide ban? These can be caused only by the CMs.

What are the rules in this case? Do they have the possibility to intervene/appeal it?

Comment: Note: although I can see some people with a 10-year cage, I have no way to know, what they did. I can imagine deeds for what I would say, the cage is okay. (For example, technical attack against the site network, or commiting anything criminally punishable against the SE.)

Comment: For a ban of that length, would you not agree this is to avoid them causing more problems to SE? Communication is possibly less than important. See as an example, spammers - we don't communicate with them, we just destroy the account.

Comment: I'm also a bit puzzled as to your continued use of the word cage - it is very much not the effect of a suspension. A suspension prevents someone posting, it is not like a cage in any way. They have time to cool off and possibly learn how to behave in future.

Comment: @RoryAlsop I use this word, because I think it is better. I could choose to use the official, but longer and badly euphemistic "temporary suspension". The reason for me to not doing this, is that my question will be downvoted to the hell, independently from the my actually used terminology - thus, there is no reason for me to follow anything what the voters want from me.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking... as far as I'm aware, suspensions require a mod message... mod messages give the user a single opportunity to reply... if they waste it, that's their own fault. I'm also pretty sure that anyone can submit a form through the contact page...

Comment: @peterh using the wrong terminology makes it harder for everybody to understand what you mean, and yes, is likely to get downvotes as it just seems deliberately awkward.

Comment: Also "hilarious offender"?

Comment: @Catija It is not about the "ordinary" mod suspensions. They happen only a single site. It is about the network-wide suspensions, their maximal length is 10 years (although the database limit is 9999-12-31), they can be given only by the CMs. [And example of such an account](https://stackexchange.com/users/528458/ron-maimon?tab=accounts), currently in 10-year long "leave".

Comment: @RoryAlsop I think the word "cage" and "ban" are understood perfectly well here, only the "community" wants somehow always from me, to use the official and euphemistic "temporary suspension". But the community doesn't treat me even a single bit better if I do this, so I have no reason to do.

Comment: No - at least in my culture cage is entirely different. The meaning is completely different. The community would like you to use words they understand, generally. I know I would. If you have no reason not to, I would suggest using standard nomenclature will avoid at least some of the downvotes you typically get.

Comment: @Catija It is a little bit irony, I don't know, how it comes out in English, but I think the post is mainly comprehensible.

Comment: It doesn't. Hilarious means very funny... I don't generally feel that needing to suspend people is funny.

Comment: @Catija Ok, thanks. I removed that word from the post.

Comment: @peterh I can find no references to Jeff Atwood talking about "a day in the cage" anywhere, and plenty to "a day in the penalty box" dating back to 2009.

Comment: That's because the domain changed, the .blog address is relatively new. That TLD didn't even become active until mid-2016.

Comment: @peterh - how strange. I don't remember that at all. And all the archives from back then have penalty box...

Comment: See https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/ for the old domain, it looks like you've imagined it.

Comment: @RoryAlsop Could you find any snapshots of this page earlier as around 2015? I tried, but I couldn't.

Comment: I'm not going to spend more time chasing this down. Frankly it seems pretty likely that Jeff used a common sporting metaphor that aptly describes the situation and you're wrong, certainly considering the alternative is a wide ranging conspiracy to delete this from search engines and the way back machine.

Comment: @peterh You are imagining things. That blog post has been a day in the penalty box [since it was created](https://web.archive.org/web/20090409100347/http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/). It was never changed.

Comment: @animuson No. I still clearly remember the term "cage" from official SE source. But I accept that this blog post used always the "penalty box" terminology. Thanks the link!

Comment: @peterh - it works perfectly well for millions of native and non-native speakers. Yes, we get you have many problems with specific words in the English language, but they, to be honest, are your problem. English is not an incredibly difficult language - if you make an effort it will benefit your interactions with others on SE.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

General network-wide suspensions for only a year usually are accompanied by a message from a staff member on a random site or a direct email to explain why.

Ten-year suspensions are usually reserved for people who rise to the level of "active troll" - they've generally repeatedly ignored messages or emails, or responded to them with very inappropriate and aggressive messages that indicate they have a desire to continue with their behavior. They are also sometimes used to lock repeated-use sock-puppet accounts so they can't keep being recreated with an association bonus. Sending them another message about it is entirely pointless. It would just be extremely repetitive information.

If there was *any* chance of a 10-year suspension being revoked, we wouldn't have issued the 10-year suspension in the first place.

Comment: What happens if they come back after 10 years?

Comment: @Sonic Don't know. I guess we'll find out if anyone ever does return after a 10-year suspension. One hasn't elapsed yet.

Comment: 10 years is enough for serious personality changes, thus I think, they deserve a second chance. Furthermore, you had the option to "temporary" suspend them for longer them, the maximal value of the relevant date field is 9999-12-31.

Comment: Gosh, those active trolls sound terrible. Hope I don't have to interact with one!

Comment: @jonrsharpe It is your decision, who do you call troll. Thus, the answer depends on you.